# ERROR 1231 (42000) with sql_mode when trying to import a sql dump in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to import a dump of a database to my localhost in MySQL Workbench.
At the moment of trying to import a dump of MySQL version 5.7 to a 8.0.14 version, I get this error:

> ERROR 1231 (42000) at line 198: Variable `sql_mode` can't be set to the value of `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER`
>
> Operation failed with exitcode `1`

The problem is that the dump has a size of 4GB and I can't open it beacause my PC freezes. Is there a form of remove this line or solve this problem?

Comment: You probably can't open it in any regular text editor, but you can do a search-replace for a particular line that's causing trouble. Tools like `perl` or `sed` can do this easily. Are you trying to load a dump from a newer version to an older version of MySQL? Remember `mysqldump` has a whole bunch of options, so you can disable parts of the dump that are problematic.

Comment: I'm trying to run a dump file of a older version of MySQL to a newer version.
How can I disable that parts of code?

Comment: Is upgrading locally a viable option? If you can get the versions in sync the process is usually a lot smoother. A bunch of things changed in 8.0, but upgrading should be seamless enough.

Comment: Can I upgrade it without having the database in the localhost?

Comment: Open dump in `EditPad Pro` and comment out he line 198

Comment: @SSpoke The problem is that the file size is of 4GB. Can I open it in EditPad Pro?

Comment: You seem to have hit [this MySQL 8.0 bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90624)... The bug report says it was fixed on 8.0.13, but since you are using 8.0.14 this might not be the case...

Comment: Are you running Windows, or a unix/linux system? Do you have perl installed? Or maybe `sed` utility?

Comment: @GMB I have Windows 10, I had installed Perl because of one of the comments in this question, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: use findstr /V  NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER your_file . will output all lines without this contains NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER

Comment: or better use the --force option like this: **mysql -u root -pxxxx --force <your_file** you can also add the database to use

Comment: EditPad Pro i think can open files up to 2 GB in size max.. so ya sorry that wont work.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to have hit [this MySQL 8.0 bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90624). The bug page says it's fixed in 8.0.13, but since you are using 8.0.14 and still meeting the problem, this might not be the case...

It also suggest a workaround : *replace all instances of `,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER` with nothing*. If you are not able to open the file with a text editor because it is too big, you can use Perl to update the file in place with a regular expression, like:

```
perl -pi -e 's/,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER//g' file
```

Flags explanation:

- `-e` causes the Perl code to be executed
- `-p` means : execute the code for each file line
- `-i` means : edit the file in-place

Comment: I do this in the PerlCritic Desktop App or in MySQL Workbench?